# How to remove any string inside square brackets

Tags: javascript

I copied some paragraphs from http://ar.wikipedia.org
that contain many of [15] , [89] , [etc..]
I want we remove automatically the [ ] with anything in it with JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Provide a short sample paragraph in your question?

Comment: `"some_text[15]".replace(/\[\d+\]/, '')` replaces all `[]` with numbers in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular exp.

```
test = "[5] new value";    
test = test.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/, '$1');
alert(test);
```

### Update

```
test = "FIFA publishes its results according to IFRS. The total compensation for the management committee in 2011 was 30 million for 35 persons. Blatter, the only full time, earns approx 2 Mio CHF, 1.2 Mio fix, the rest bonus.[4][5][6]";
test = test.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, '$1');//for global replace
alert(test);
```

## [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/n9buA/3/)